# Mark the highest-voted answer as accepted on another person's question

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, accepted-answer

I have seen multiple questions which are made of very good points, but the asker has his own different approach of seeing each and every answer. That is the reason, probably, that sometimes the OP accepts an answer which is not 100% suitable to the question.

Then other answers get more up votes than the accepted answer. That can be misleading for other SO users looking for the right solution.

Is there any way to accept the most upvoted answer instead of the less upvoted answer accepted by the OP?

Assume that I have enough reputation to make that decision whether it should be accepted or not.

Is there any possible way to do that?

Comment: You are referring to other user's questions rather than your own? *No one* except the asker ever chooses which answer is accepted.

Comment: I suspect that you are thinking of that green checkmark as meaning *"correct"*. Well, it doesn't. It means *"I used this solution to my problem"*. Nothing more; nothing less.

Comment: First, the votes reflect the communities choice, but the accepted answer only reflects that it helped the OP. Second, how else are we supposed to get the pirate hat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP asked the question, and he got an answer which solved his problem. So he accepted that answer. There might be another answer which is more helpful to the community, but that should not influence OP's decision. It is as it should be.

If you like a different answer to the accepted one, **you can upvote it**. That is what up vote is for.

Simply You can

1. Upvote the unaccepted answer if you find it is useful
2. Down vote the accepted answer if it is **TERRIBLY BAD**.
3. Politely tell Original Poster to reconsider the accept via a comment, but the final decision should be in OP's hands.

That is only you can do.. Only Original Poster can accept the answer, and it should be like that.

Answer (score 5):

Only the original poster can accept an answer. This makes the most logical sense (it's their problem, they *should* know if an answer solves it) but try reading [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/169404)

It is fine if another answer is getting more up votes. Votes don't necessarily mean anything either.

> Assume that I have enough reputations to make that decision whether it should accept or not.

Reputation has nothing to do with you being in a position to make this decision. However, you **can** comment on posts.

Also, the answer with the highest score might be added after the OP accepts an answer (but later on the user can change what answer he/she accepts). Or the OP just disagrees with you. Who knows?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such option to accept an answer if we are not the OP. Only OP can accept the answer on his question. **Just upvote an unaccepted answer if it is useful**. Everyone will see unaccepted and upvoted answers if he/she don't find the solution from the accepted answer.